# why linkbutton event fire when page refresh(f5)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have bound data from database with datalist.

There is next and prev buttons in datalist footer template. The problem is that when I click next button all works well but when I refresh the page (f5), the next button event fire again.

Please explain why after refresh or postback the linkbutton event fires.

Comment: refresh the Page (F5) = Page Load with postback..

Comment: whats your code for paging???

Answer (score 0):

Bind the datasource for datalist in page `prerender` event. This fire after the control event in the page lifecycle.